# How do i find all elements of value R in a matrix that are neighboring an element of value K? - Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix with values of 1, 0, and 2 and i wish to change all the zeros that neighbor a 2 into 2's. Any efficient way of going forward with this problem?

The final problem that need's to be solved is that i need to "color" all the 0's that can be reached from a group of initially set 2's in the matrix. (run the above "function" n^2 times), one can think of the problem as a peculation problem where the 1's are the blocked sites of a rectangular grid.

Comment: post something that your try'ed out and ask for what's wrong in it!

Comment: Use `imdilate` to "grow" the locations of 2's and get all their neighbors.

Comment: @Vignesh I know how to write a function that preforms the above, yet i am searching for an efficient way of approaching the problem, (currently i do the "coloring" step, looking for neighbors, which is O(n^2) and then run it n^2 times, in order to find all the reachable sites, finally reaching O(n^4))

Comment: @Naveh I wish to only "grow" into locations that previously had a 0, not onto 1's.

Comment: Dilation gets you the neighbors. Finding the zeros is easy enough. Now put them together

Comment: i am thinking that there might be a way to mathematically change the matrix as a hole, which will dramatically increase the efficiency of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First define neighborhood. If you want 8 neighbors use this kernel:

```
kernel = [1 1 1;1 0 1; 1 1 1];
```

If you want 4 direct neighbors use this kernel:

```
kernel = [0 1 0;1 0 1; 0 1 0];
```

You can use [conv2](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html) to test if the neighborhood of a point contains 2.

```
test_neighbors = conv2(A==2, kernel,'same') > 0;
```

the value of the point should also be 0

```
test_A = A == 0;
```

then both conditions should be satisfied:

```
test = test_neighbors & test_A;
```

set those points to 2

```
A(test) = 2;
```

all in one:

```
A(conv2(A==2, kernel,'same') & ~A)=2;
```

Comment: @UriPe'er Glad if it can help!